# What is wrong with this example in Dietel's "C: How to Program" book?

Tags: c, string, pointers, uppercase

I'm studying C: How to program by Dietel. in Pointers chapter, there is this example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void convertToUppercase(char *sPtr);

int main( void )
{
    char string[] = "cHaRaCters and $32.98";
    printf( "The string before conversion is: %s", string );
    convertToUppercase( string );
    printf( "\nThe string after conversion is: %s\n", string );
}

void convertToUppercase(char *sPtr)
{
    while(*sPtr != '\0') {
        *sPtr = toupper(*sPtr);
        ++*sPtr;
    }
}
```

when I compile it, there is no problem. but when I run it, nothing happens. I can't find out what is the problem!

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: Skill #2 in writing software is learning to debug.  SO is not  a debugger.

Comment: `++*sPtr` try `++sPtr`

Comment: @Ôrel Good point. Is it the exact code as in the book? Then I would suggest to trash it and take another one without typos.

Comment: @EugeneSh. it's a book. OP probably created the code with manual OCR => typo

Comment: "when I run it, nothing happens" That only seems so. There should happen a lot (and you can see this in the debugger). Depending on input (first character <= `z`) it can loop infinitely. You might notice the loud noise of your CPU cooler if you wait long enough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in the function

```
void convertToUppercase(char *sPtr)
{
    while(*sPtr != '\0') {
        *sPtr = toupper(*sPtr);
        ++*sPtr;
        ^^^^^^^^
    }
}
```

Instead there must be

```
        ++sPtr;
        ^^^^^^^
```

This expression `++*sPtr` increments the character pointed to by the pointer `sPtr` while this expression `++sPtr` increments the pointer itself.

Nevertheless the code has several drawbacks.

There is a convention for string functions in the C Standard that they should return pointers to target strings. So it is musch better to declare the function like

```
char * convertToUppercase(char *sPtr);
```

Also the function `toupper` relies on that its argument can be represented as unsigned character.

From the C Standard (7.4 Character handling )

> 1 The header  declares several functions useful for
>   classifying and mapping characters.198) **In all cases the argument is
>   an int, the value of which shall be representable as an unsigned char
>   or shall equal the value of the macro EOF.** If the argument has any
>   other value, the behavior is undefined.

So it will be more correctly to write

```
        *sPtr = toupper( ( unsigned char )*sPtr);
```

And a `for` loop will be more appropriate than `while` loop in this case.

Taking all this into account the function can be implemented the following way

```
char * convertToUppercase(char *sPtr)
{
    for ( char *p = sPtr; *p != '\0'; ++p ) {
        *p = toupper( ( unsigned char )*p );
    }

    return sPtr;
}
```

and called like

```
printf( "\nThe string after conversion is: %s\n", convertToUppercase( string ) );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast and clear answer.

Comment: Btw, I checked the book again. I did the type and in the book it is correct.

Comment: @MiladSoltani In any case somebody made a typo.:)

Answer (score 6):

you need to increment the pointer not the value change `++*sPtr` to `++sPtr`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void convertToUppercase(char *sPtr);

int main( void )
{
    char string[] = "cHaRaCters and $32.98";
    printf( "The string before conversion is: %s", string );
    convertToUppercase( string );
    printf( "\nThe string after conversion is: %s\n", string );
}

void convertToUppercase(char *sPtr)
{
    while(*sPtr != '\0') {
        *sPtr = toupper(*sPtr);
        ++sPtr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. I checked the book again and I saw that I did the typo.